# Using Python Libraries in Java (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, praw

I am currently creating a discord bot in Java and decided to write a script in python as it had libraries that proved very useful for web scraping. By using Jython, I was able to run the script. The bot successfully came online, however, it resulted in the following:

`ImportError: No module named praw`

When I run the python script by itself in another IDE, it works perfectly. I was wondering if I have to add praw as a dependency in gradle? Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3 you need to use pip3 when installing packages

`$ pip3 install praw`

Comment: This is not the problem, I have installed the package already but my Java IDE (IntelliJ) is not recognising it for some reason.